# Suggestion on UIView layout

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, custom-view, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to create a 4x4 grid of squares (each square separated by some space).  As a user pans his finger from one square to the other, I want to highlight the squares and draw line between the squares (to show that they are connected).

I have created a GridView custom UIView and 16 child GridElement custom UIViews laid out as 4x4 and I want use pan gesture to select the squares and drawline. Is that the right way to proceed?

Thanks for the response. So I tried what you suggested. Now, I have made individual grid squares subclasses of UIControl and the containing view is the target of their actions. My containing view is a subclass of UIView. The containing view receives the UIControlEventTouchDown event but does not receive UIControlEventTouchDragExit or (Enter)

```
- (void) sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendAction:action to:target forEvent:event]; 
}

- (void) sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents {
    [super sendActionsForControlEvents:controlEvents];
}

- (BOOL) beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return YES;
}
```

In my ContainerView I have

```
[gridElement addTarget:self action:@selector(elementSelected:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
```

Comment: Have you checked out the new UICollectionViewController docs?

Comment: Of course, it's still in beta til the 19th so you'll need a developer license to access this info until then.

Comment: @Jamie that would only help with the (easy) grid part, not the (harder) interaction part.

Answer (score 2):

This will only select the first square once the finger has moved enough to be considered a pan- you may need to add another recogniser to pick up the first touch.

If I were doing this, I'd approach it differently. You could make your individual grid squares UIControl subclasses, and make your containing view the target for their actions. UIControls already respond to events such as touch down inside, touch drag entered, touch up inside etc. you can pass these events to the containing view and highlight/draw lines as appropriate as the user moves their finger around.

Comment: See my further question below